# PNG Images crashing on iPhone and other mobile devices

Tags: wordpress, image, mobile, png

I really have no idea why this is happening and I really hope someone had this issue before! My current problem is I'm running an ecommerce website with approx. 2500 products. All product images are in PNG format because the must be transparent (Design-Requirement). On Desktop everything works fine, going on mobile the Images start crashing or however you would call that. Images are being replaced by already loaded ones and sometimes they reverse colors.

All images are in RGB / PNG-24 (Size: 732 x 732 px).

The code I'm using in case of relevance:

```
<img    title"{{ product.name }}"
        alt="{{ product.name }}"
        itemprop="contentUrl"
        class="product-img"
        src="{{ product.thumbnail.src }}"
        srcset="{{ product.thumbnail.src|resize(250, 250)|retina(1) }} 1x,
        {{ product.thumbnail.src|resize(250, 250)|retina(2) }} 2x,
        {{ product.thumbnail.src|resize(250, 250)|retina(3) }} 3x,
        {{ product.thumbnail.src|resize(250, 250)|retina(4) }} 4x" />
```

The shop runs on Wordpress / WooCommerce and uses Timber Twig for templating. In my opinion this is an image error not a code problem.

Any help appreciated :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: The basics is, when Safari runs out of memory, weird stuff happens.  You have to load and unload whatever is in view at the time to manage the load.

Comment: @TrevorD Okay unfortunately I was a bit fast with my reply, after more testing it also appears on Chrome for iOS...

Comment: Check the images with `pngcheck`. Also, do you exclusively use out-of-the-box software to create them, or do you use additional utilities such as postprocessing them with zopfli?

Comment: All PNG's are fine although I currently think that @TrevorD is right, but it has nothing todo with Safari, it's the entire device running out of memory... Im only using out-of-the-box software!

Comment: Technically Chrome on iOS is Safari in chrome drag.  iTunes agreement states you must use the Safari engine (UIWebView). So iOS chrome is just skinned UIWebView.  That means it has all the same problems with memory.  I am not sure if this helps you because you need the transparency, but weirdly, the canvas uses less memory than the img.  So if you are able, you can use canvas instead, and each get a hook to load an image and draw it to the canvas.  This also saves memory if the the image is resized down. I do something similar in a cordova app that takes full resolution images and shows thumbs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously this hand nothing todo with any image format or similar.. While surfing for another problem I found this Blogpost about "iOS6 html hardware acceleration changes and how to fix them".

http://indiegamr.com/ios6-html-hardware-acceleration-changes-and-how-to-fix-them/

Pretty old, but still a problem on iOS 11. I am using filter so set a shadow on my image. All was working but not on the iPhone. So I added following lines:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

That's it! :)

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is Safari is running out of memory.  This can result in strange artifacts, or the page crashing entirely, leaving only a shell of the app remaining.

All browsers on iOS use UIWebView internally, so even Chrome will show this issue.

The only way to solve this is to limit how much you load to the page.  Try to only show images that need to be shown, and hide what the user isn't looking at.  Use a pager if needed, or dynamically resize all images before displaying them.

A weird trick I have used previously is to load all images to canvas elements instead.  These typically have a smaller memory footprint.  Canvas does not support transparency directly but you can draw things on top of each other to simulate it.

A basic way to handle changing all images to canvas is like this

```js
    $(function(){
        $("canvas").each(function(){
            var newImage = new Image();
            var self=this;
            var ctx = self.getContext("2d");          
            newImage.onload = function () {
               var orgWidth = newImage.naturalWidth;
               var orgHeight = newImage.naturalHeight;
               ctx.drawImage(newImage, 0, 0, orgWidth, orgHeight, 0, 0, self.width, self.height);
            };   
            newImage.src = $(self).data("url");     
        });
    });
```

```css
canvas{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas data-url="https://www.google.ca/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"></canvas>
```